# How big is an android phone's screen?

Tags: android, motorola-droid

How big is the smallest motorola android's screen, in pixels? I want to know what size I need to make my graphic without it being too distorted by the fill_parent.

Comment: I think you mean the Motorola Droid.  Android is the name for the platform running on all Android phones.

Comment: 1. There are many different phones with Android (Android is the OS) and I think you are looking for http://www.motorola.com/Consumers/XW-EN/Consumer-Products-and-Services/Mobile-Phones/ci.Motorola-MILESTONE-XW-EN.alt

2. Please don't use fixed layouts for one display size, there are so many phones with different resolutions which might not be able to use your App 'cause you designed it just for one phone. Flexible layouts are much better in view of portability (take a look at Draw 9-patch).

Comment: Why was that tagged as "eclipse" and "gimp"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

motorola droid's display size is 480x854 px, according to specs, so it's rather non-standard

Comment: Well, there is no real standard size. Creating an App. for one resolution is like buying shoes for a child and telling him/her to wear them forever. Just like the child is growing, resolutions change quite often.

Comment: @Layne maybe the autor just wants to crop/scale some image and put it on his own device only. it really is childish to even ask this type of question at SO. it's not childish to answer childish questions

Comment: My apologies. We were just looking out for you. :) Glad you got what you were looking for.

Answer (score 9):

Although this doesn't directly answer your question..

Android is the name of the operating system running on Android phones. Different phone models could have different resolutions and pixel densities. Therefore you have to be careful not to hardcode resolution values into your code. It might run well on one phone but poorly on another.

Check out these pages for details about supporting different screens:

http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html
http://developer.android.com/resources/dashboard/screens.html

Answer (score 2):

It would be unwise to program for one screen size, especially if you plan on distributing your application later. You should design your application for as many screen sizes as possible.

Instead use [nine-patch images](http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/tools/draw9patch.html) and flexible layouts.
If you are designing an icon, the look at the [android icon design guidelines](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/ui_guidelines/icon_design.html) and consider high, medium and low density screens. There are different resource folders for these too and android takes care of selecting the appropriate one for the current device.